# Why is my answer off for certain values of binary representation provided?

Tags: c++, binary

The question basically asks us to convert the input binary string (only 1 and 0 provided).
Input format is as follows (each separate point is a new line):

- Number of test cases
- 2N lines with: Length of binary string, Binary string on each alternative line
  Output is to return the decimal conversion of the string.

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    while(t--){
        int len;
        cin >> len;
        long long num = 0;
        while(len--){
            char digit;
            cin >> digit;
            num += (digit-'0')*pow(2,len);
        }
        cout << num << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Ik there are other methods to go about this problem, but i want to know whats the problem in mine. Inputting certain values like '10001011111110111010111011010011011011110001011000011101' gives an answer '39401750052935200' when the correct value is '39401750052935197'.

Other examples of wrong output:

- 269908306298371776 (correct = 269908306298371795)
- 1152921504606846976 (correct =   1152921504606846975)

My code runs correct for all smaller values of binary input (of length maybe less than 50). Why does it fail for such larger values by such a small margin?

Comment: integer overflow

Comment: Don’t use `pow` for powers of 2.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude sorry for the improper editing, fixed it now

Comment: @justANewbie how so? im using long long integers, which can store values upto 2^63 - 1. the question constraints have upto 60 digits in the binary string which is atmost 2^61 - 1

Comment: @PaulR what should i use as a substitute? and why does using `pow` give error?

Comment: `pow` is a floating point function, using floating point arithmetic to calculate the result. For powers of 2 you can use plain integers and shift `<<`.

Comment: `pow` uses floating point, which on Python is typically 53 bits of precision. Longer than that drops bits. Use integer bit shifting instead.

Comment: okay, thank you, ill try bit shifting and check it out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> runs correct for all smaller values of binary input (of length maybe less than 50).

`num += (digit-'0')*pow(2,len);` is like

`num = num + (digit-'0')*pow(2,len);`

and the addition is done using `double` math with its 53-ish bit precision *infected* by `pow()`.

---

Instead only use integer math:

```
unsigned long long num = 0;
...
  num = num*2 + (digit-'0');
```